# Toggle between desktop site and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Created a responsive layout for website. Now client needs to add a button in footer to toggle between mobile view and desktop site. I used bootstrap for the front-end. I heard that the responsiveness handled with this code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I tried with this code and test it. But no luck.

```
<span id="desktopswitch">desktop version</span>

$('#desktopswitch').on('click', function() {
    $('#viewport').attr('content','width=1024, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1');
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the meta tag has no `id="viewport"`. Use `$( '[name=viewport]' )` instead. But that won't work either. You need to remove it completely.

Comment: $("#viewport").text("@media (min-width: 1024px) {}}"); Try @media in jquery.

Comment: @lumio So you have any idea to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `$( '[name=viewport]' ).remove()` - https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: @lumio Yes. No any luck

Comment: Ah wait - sorry my bad. You might still have your @media-queries, right? Hm - maybe then your approach is better. But use `$( '[name=viewport]' )` as selector.

Comment: @lumio Still no luck